# Homebrew, Python3 and additional packages

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I installed Python3 with Homebrew:

```
$ brew install python3
```

Everything went fine, but Python3 installed additional packages:

- gdbm,
- openssl,
- python3,
- readline, and
- sqlite.

I'm using OS X Yosemite and not sure if replacing OpenSSL is a good idea. I would like to know your opinion. As far as I know OpenSSL is part of the OS X base system.

Your time is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of homebrew is that it never replaces anything on the host system. Everything is contained in its own package hierarchy under `Cellar`. That version of OpenSSL will only be used by other packages installed by homebrew.